# TF object detection API detection model retraining: "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_version"

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm retraining ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29 using Tensorflow Object Detection API and I get this particular error on both Windows and Ubuntu environments.
My environment below is Windows 10 with python 3.6.9, cuda 9.0, and tensorflow 1.15 I used protobuf 3.13.0.
I did the installation test and it was okay, so now I'm trying with my own dataset and getting the following error

```
  google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 141:3 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_version".
```

The config file that I used

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 FPN-lite (go/fpn-lite) feature extractor, shared box
# predictor and focal loss (a mobile version of Retinanet).
# Retinanet: see Lin et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint
# Train on TPU-8
#
# Achieves 28.2 mAP on COCO17 Val

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 3
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 128
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true,
            decay: 0.997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
        kernel_size: 3
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras'
      use_depthwise: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.01
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/me1eye/New folder/29082020/models/research/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/mobilenet_v2.ckpt-1"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
  batch_size: 128
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 50000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .08
          total_steps: 50000
          warmup_learning_rate: .026666
          warmup_steps: 1000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "D:/me1eye/New folder/29082020/models/research/object_detection/labelmap.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/me1eye/New folder/29082020/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "D:/me1eye/New folder/29082020/models/research/object_detection/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/me1eye/New folder/29082020/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
}
```

List of installed packages:

```
Package                         Version
------------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                         0.10.0
argon2-cffi                     20.1.0
astor                           0.8.1
astunparse                      1.6.3
attrs                           20.1.0
backcall                        0.2.0
bleach                          3.1.5
cachetools                      4.1.1
certifi                         2020.6.20
cffi                            1.14.2
chardet                         3.0.4
colorama                        0.4.3
contextlib2                     0.6.0.post1
cycler                          0.10.0
Cython                          0.29.21
dataclasses                     0.7
decorator                       4.4.2
defusedxml                      0.6.0
dill                            0.3.2
dm-tree                         0.1.5
docutils                        0.16
entrypoints                     0.3
future                          0.18.2
gast                            0.2.2
gin-config                      0.3.0
google-api-core                 1.22.1
google-api-python-client        1.11.0
google-auth                     1.21.0
google-auth-httplib2            0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib            0.4.1
google-cloud-bigquery           1.27.2
google-cloud-core               1.4.1
google-crc32c                   1.0.0
google-pasta                    0.2.0
google-resumable-media          1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos        1.52.0
grpcio                          1.31.0
h5py                            2.10.0
httplib2                        0.18.1
idna                            2.10
importlib-metadata              1.7.0
ipykernel                       5.3.4
ipython                         7.16.1
ipython-genutils                0.2.0
ipywidgets                      7.5.1
jedi                            0.17.2
Jinja2                          2.11.2
jsonschema                      3.2.0
jupyter                         1.0.0
jupyter-client                  6.1.7
jupyter-console                 6.2.0
jupyter-core                    4.6.3
kaggle                          1.5.6
Keras-Applications              1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing             1.1.2
keyring                         21.3.1
kiwisolver                      1.2.0
lxml                            4.5.2
Markdown                        3.2.2
MarkupSafe                      1.1.1
matplotlib                      3.3.1
mistune                         0.8.4
nbconvert                       5.6.1
nbformat                        5.0.7
notebook                        6.1.3
numpy                           1.18.5
oauthlib                        3.1.0
opencv-python-headless          4.4.0.42
opt-einsum                      3.3.0
packaging                       20.4
pandas                          1.1.1
pandocfilters                   1.4.2
parso                           0.7.1
pickleshare                     0.7.5
Pillow                          7.2.0
pip                             20.2.2
pkginfo                         1.5.0.1
prometheus-client               0.8.0
promise                         2.3
prompt-toolkit                  3.0.6
protobuf                        3.13.0
psutil                          5.7.2
py-cpuinfo                      7.0.0
pyasn1                          0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                  0.2.8
pycocotools-windows             2.0.0.2
pycparser                       2.20
Pygments                        2.6.1
pyparsing                       2.4.7
pyrsistent                      0.16.0
python-dateutil                 2.8.1
python-slugify                  4.0.1
pytz                            2020.1
pywin32                         228
pywin32-ctypes                  0.2.0
pywinpty                        0.5.7
PyYAML                          5.3.1
pyzmq                           19.0.2
qtconsole                       4.7.6
QtPy                            1.9.0
readme-renderer                 26.0
requests                        2.24.0
requests-oauthlib               1.3.0
requests-toolbelt               0.9.1
rfc3986                         1.4.0
rsa                             4.6
scipy                           1.4.1
Send2Trash                      1.5.0
sentencepiece                   0.1.91
setuptools                      49.6.0.post20200814
six                             1.15.0
tensorboard                     1.15.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit          1.7.0
tensorflow                      1.15.0
tensorflow-addons               0.11.2
tensorflow-datasets             3.2.1
tensorflow-estimator            1.15.1
tensorflow-hub                  0.9.0
tensorflow-metadata             0.23.0
tensorflow-model-optimization   0.4.1
tensorflow-object-detection-api 0.1.1
termcolor                       1.1.0
terminado                       0.8.3
testpath                        0.4.4
text-unidecode                  1.3
tf-models-official              2.3.0
tf-slim                         1.1.0
tornado                         6.0.4
tqdm                            4.48.2
traitlets                       4.3.3
twine                           3.2.0
typeguard                       2.9.1
uritemplate                     3.0.1
urllib3                         1.24.3
wcwidth                         0.2.5
webencodings                    0.5.1
Werkzeug                        1.0.1
wheel                           0.35.1
widgetsnbextension              3.5.1
wincertstore                    0.2
wrapt                           1.12.1
zipp                            3.1.0
```

Error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 93, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py", line 98, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 734, in Merge
    allow_unknown_field=allow_unknown_field)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 802, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 827, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 849, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 974, in _MergeField
    merger(tokenizer, message, field)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 1048, in _MergeMessageField
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
  File "D:\me1eye\New folder\Anaconda3\envs\29082020\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 941, in _MergeField
    (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 141:3 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_version".
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete "fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2" in config file.