# with AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

***I am trying to build an object detection model with the help of tensorflow and having this error again and again. I tried that tf.io.Gfile also, but it is not helpful. I am using tensorflow 2.2.0 version and tensorflow-GPU 2.2.0 as well. Here is the code,***

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}

**when I change the tf.gfile to tf.io.gfile, here comes the new error....**

I tried and now facing this....

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in

```
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
```

File "C:\Users\91880\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages
\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)

File "C:\Users\91880\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
label_map_string = fid.read()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 122, in read
self._preread_check()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\compat.py", line 71, in as_bytes
(bytes_or_text,))

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item {

name: "Namaste"
id: 1
}

item {
name: "Thanks"
id: 2
}

item {
name: "Yes"
id: 3
}

item {
name: "No"
id: 4
}

item {
name: "Good"
id: 5
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade the TensorFlow version to 1.15 and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Please see the above comment...This is the new error I am facing

Comment: I don't have github link, but here is the youtube video link.....

youtube video----->>> https://youtu.be/V0Pk_dPU2lY

time stamp 50:01

Comment: Run it without replacing `tf.gfile` with `tf.io.gfile` as well as downgrading the tensorflow version to 1.15 and try

Comment: In the `generate_tfrecords.py` file, remove line 61 and change line 62 to
`label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(args.labels_path)
`

Comment: Thanks a lot bhai....really thank you....
I just downgrade my tensorflow to tensorflow=1.15 and tensorflow-gpu=1.15 version and used Cuda 10.0 and Cudnn10.0 version with it....

Your comment of removal of line 61 and adding 62 line solved my problem...

Comment: bro can you help one more time, I am having some different error in that code...timeStamp 1.00.10 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0Pk_dPU2lY..
Error : ParseError: 172:3 : Message type "object_detection.protos.TrainConfig" has no field named "fine_tune_checkpoint_version".

Comment: If it's a different question, please post a new question. About the error, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652488/tf-object-detection-api-detection-model-retraining-object-detection-protos-tra) answer your question?