# Why Tensorflow has no attribute 'gfile' even after I changed the file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I got error **AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'** so I found online that now we have to change `tf.gfile` to `tf.io.gfile`
so I changed it in the `C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py` but still it is not working for me.

*Error:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-efc7822bb0d7> in <module>
----> 1 config = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\config_util.py in get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config_path, config_override)
     94   """
     95   pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
---> 96   with tf.io.gfile.GFile(pipeline_config_path, "r") as f:
     97     proto_str = f.read()
     98     text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

Can anyone can help me out?
I am new to this

Comment: Do not post an image of the code and the error.

Comment: @yudhiesh But why? I wanted to show the error

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

downgrade to tensorflow 2.3.0
by

> pip install tensorflow==2.3.0

you can see the diffrent versions from `https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#install_the_package`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `import tensorflow as tf` with `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and check if it works

Comment: If possible, please share the link of the notebook that you have used

Comment: https://github.com/nicknochnack/RealTimeObjectDetection

Comment: What is the TensorFlow version that you're using?

Comment: it's 2.4.1, i just used `!pip install tensorfow`, i think it is the latest one

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703065/with-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-gfile/66721283) post answer your question?